# Looking for a manga: female lead in college who had an abusive father and meets a popular band member

Tags: identification-request, manga

I’m looking for this old manga I read, it’s more slice of life with a female lead in college. She has been living with her boyfriend who she met in high school. She had a abusive father and moved away with her boyfriend. She finds him cheating on her when she comes home. When she goes out she meets a popular band member and they spend the night together. Now she’s breaking up and trying to figure things out with this new guy. Also spoiler: the girl her boyfriend cheats with is the little sister of a band member in the same group as the new guy.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Comedown Machine](https://m.tapas.io/series/comedownmachine/info?gclid=Cj0KCQiAi8KfBhCuARIsADp-A54-xtvsv7xXKypMhi17znecF8ElarLCJs_yKxtEf3sM2suKMa6nBpMaAoOCEALw_wcB#) (Story by Amapora & Art by Saza), published on Tapas:

> After Tommy finds out that her long-term boyfriend is cheating on her, she jumps into a relationship with a celebrity in the city. As their relationship develops, so do their problems, especially as Tommy continues living with her ex! In this story about relationships, struggles, and moving on, nothing is what it seems...

Tommy doesn't realize who the "celebrity" is at first, but it's soon revealed he is a member of her ex's favorite band. The other woman is Tessa, who is later revealed to be the half sister of another band member, Howe.